# conflicting libraries in usage

Tags: gcc, shared-libraries, libcrypto

I am trying to compile a binary which links to libcrypto.so.1.1 and my binary also links against another library (Let us call this library libblah.so)

This libblah.so links against libcrypto.so.1.0. During the compilation, I get a warning saying that there is a conflicting linking of library for libcrypto.

Though, I am not directly linking libcrypto 1.0 and 1.1 in my 1st level of linking, I am seeing this error. I am interested in understanding what issues might this cause during the runtime.